# Can "v4l2loopback" be installed/compiled for FreeBSD 13.1?

Tags: freebsd, ffmpeg, camera, video-encoding, v4l2loopback

Wondering if anyone was able to compile v4l2loopback for FreeBSD 13.1

If so what are the steps.

I need it for FFMPEG to convert a live USB cam MJPEG video stream from yuv422 to yuv420 on the fly and also need it for running multiple instances of the same video feed of the USB capture card/webcam device.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into `webcamd` package.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's already built in. From [webcamd(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=webcamd&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports):

> -c         Create device of specified type. Valid values: v4l2loopback For
> multiple v4l2loopback devices, specify
>
> ```
>      -m v4l2loopback.devices=2
> ```